# 何故Redisクラスタのハッシュスロット数は16384か

Tags: redis

何故Redisクラスタのハッシュスロット数は16384という数値なのでしょうか？ハッシュスロット数を変更したいとかではなく16384である理由が知りたいです。数値的には16x1024で何らかの上限値な感じはしますが…。

Comment: 16*1024=2^14ですね、理由は分かりませんが……

Answer (score 4):

まさしくその内容について作者に質問をするIssueがありました。

> 1. 通常のheartbeat packetはノードの完全な設定を運んでいるので、設定を書き換えることができる。
>    つまり、スロットの設定を、N=1.6万個のスロットがあると2千個分の領域を使うが、N=6.5万個のスロットがあると8千個分もの領域を使ってしまうということを意味する。
> 2. 同時に、これ以外の設計上のトレードオフのため、Redis Clusterのマスターノードが1000個以上存在することは考えづらい。
>
> このため、1.6万個というハッシュスロット数は1000個のマスターノードを取り扱うことができ、そしてスロットの設定を生の形式で伝播するのに十分小さい値です。
> クラスタが小さい場合、圧縮するのが難しいことに注意してください。
> [why redis-cluster use 16384 slots? · Issue #2576 · antirez/redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2576)

Comment: Redisの詳細な仕様に詳しくないため、上手く翻訳できませんでした。翻訳に自信のある方の編集をお待ちしております。